# Passing down variables in Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I am using promise-mysql in my application where I need to query the information of a book, and then retrieve some books with the same author as its.

Codes:

```
return Promise.all([
    pool.query(sql, id),
]).then(data=> {
    var book = data[0][0];
    if (book.author) {
        var authorSql = "select * from authors where name = ? limit 10";
        return pool.query(authorSql, book.author);
    } else {
        return Promise.resolve(book);
    }

}).then(object=> {
    if (object.id) {
        // this is a book instance, return it back
        return object
    } else {
        // this should an array of books
        var booksWithSameAuthor = object;
        // but how to get the origin book here, something like:

        var book = xxxx
        book.recommends_by_author = booksWithSameAuthor
        return book
    }
});
```

As shown, in the second `then` function, the `object` maybe a `book` object or an array like queried data rows, in the later situation, I need the `book` object too, but I have no idea how to pass it down.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful with the word `object`, it is a keyword in javascript (and many other languages) which is why it's being highlighted in blue on SO. I'd recommend using another variation like `obj`.

Comment: `object` is a keyword? I don't think so.

Comment: `return pool.query(authorSql, book.author).then(authors=>({authors, book}));` - then `booksWithSameAuther = object.authors, book = object.book;`

Comment: @Soviut `object` is not a keyword (and not even `Object` is), the reason to change it (and not to `obj`) is because it's *meaningless*.

Comment: A range of generic solutions to this issue is provided in [How-do I access previous promise results in a then chain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/)

Comment: Not really, the later promise is depend on the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that whole code snippet can be changed to

```
return Promise.all([
    pool.query(sql, id),
])
.then(data=> {
    var book = data[0][0];
    if (book.author) {
        var authorSql = "select * from authors where name = ? limit 10";
        return pool.query(authorSql, book.author)
        .then(object=>{
            book.recommends_by_author = object;
            return book;
        });
    } else {
        return book;
    }
});
```

You use a nested .then (yeah, I know, you want to avoid the pyramid) - in the nested .then you set the `recommends_by_author` property on book

Note, within the .then, the return `Promise.resolve(book)` is not required, as .then returns a Promise "by default" - so, `return book` is enough, both in the "main" .then and in the inner `.then`

Comment: You don't call nested `if` blocks a pyramid either, do you? :-D This is the correct solution, +1.

Comment: if you need to indent code, you're not doing it right :p - I may be using the wrong term, you know, callback within callback to the nth level, which is what promises are supposed to "fix" :p

Comment: to be honest, I wouldn't have the `else` around `return book` - but that's just me

Comment: I certainly indent the code in my `if` blocks for readability :-) Promises can only flatten linear chains, not branched ones - you need to flatten each branch separately. Only `async`/`await` will "fix" that problem.

Comment: @Bergi - I've yet to get my head fully around async/await - I can see it's appeal, but haven't (personally) found a real world use - besides, professionally, I still have to contend with supporting IE11 - not sure if there's an EASY way to "emulate" async/await in that dinosaur

Comment: All major transpilers seem to be able to convert it into a ES5 state machine, it's more trivial than one might think.

Comment: thanks @Bergi - I'll give babel a go at it once I fully grok the concept

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass multiple values down through the promise chain, you can pass an object, rather than a single value.

```
return {
    book: book,
    somethingElse: obj
};
```

In your next `.then()` function, you can retrieve it:

```
.then(data => {
    console.log(data.book);
    console.log(data.somethingElse);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the second pool.query with a .then and alter the book object.

```
...
  return pool.query(authorSql, book.author).then(authors => {
    book.authorList = authors;
    return Promise.resolve(book);
  });
...
```

Then you can check if book.authorList is set in your final .then().

Comment: How is `return Promise.resolve(book)` here different from just `return book`?

Comment: @torazburo The difference is that the returned promise only finishes after the second query has completed, and the authorList was added to the book object.

Comment: you only need to `return book`, not `Promise.resolve(book)` in that snippet of code

Comment: No. Semantically, they are precisely identical. I understand you just took this from the OP's code, but still it would have been nice to fix it.